# The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. error: XA2006

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono

My project is building successfully on the Debug mode, but when I change it to the Release mode; the following exception is coming:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Could not resolve reference to 'Android.Gms.Common.Internal.SafeParcel.Zza' (defined in assembly 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Places, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with scope 'Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. When the scope is different from the defining assembly, it usually means that the type is forwarded. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Gms.Common.Internal.SafeParcel.Zza
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkField(FieldReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkFields(TypeDefinition type, Boolean includeStatic, Boolean markBackingFieldsOnlyIfPropertyMarked)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() ElGas.Android
```

I try to solve this problem by uncheck SDK Linking from Droid option, now I can build my application in Release mode. But i found that if you do unCheck SDK linking it will create your .apk file too big in size. But at least I able to create Release build.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add arguments to the Skip linking assemblies, only for the library causing the issue.